# How can I swap 2 keys for a specific language/KB layout on Windows 10?

Tags: keyboard, python, script, keyboard-layout, autohotkey

I'd like to swap the <kbd>W</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd> keys, which are 'ჯ' and 'ჟ' on the desired keyboard layout, so that the <kbd>W</kbd> key outputs the latter character and the <kbd>]</kbd> key the former, and only when said keyboard is in use. How could I do this?

I know of AutoHotKey, but I don't know if it has this exact functionality. I also considered writing a Python script, but, again, I'm not sure that's easy enough to do for this problem to be within my skill level.

Answer (score 0):

At first run this Autohotkey script
and press F1 to retrieve the KeyboardLocale:

```
; Script 1

F1:: MsgBox, % InputLocaleID()

InputLocaleID() {
    ControlGetFocus, Focused, A
    ControlGet, CtrlID, Hwnd,,% Focused, A
    ThreadID := DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "Ptr", CtrlID, "Ptr", 0)
    Return, Format("{:X}", DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "UInt", ThreadID, "Ptr"))
}
```

Once retrieved, you can use the [#IF directive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/_If.htm) to [remap](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/misc/Remap.htm) the keys on the desired keyboard layout in another script, e.g.:

```
; Script 2

#IF InputLocaleID() = 4090409 ; english
    
    w::l
    l::w

#IF

InputLocaleID() {
    ControlGetFocus, Focused, A
    ControlGet, CtrlID, Hwnd,,% Focused, A
    ThreadID := DllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "Ptr", CtrlID, "Ptr", 0)
    Return, Format("{:X}", DllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "UInt", ThreadID, "Ptr"))
}
```